# Auto URL to HTML in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, url, hyperlink

How do I make URL auto recognized and changed to href html form in wordpress.

If I post:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

I want it to automaticly go to:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">My Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery but if it when wrong/slow loading on page might yield odd results so your best bet is to us something like this in PHP

```
<?php
$url_pattern = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?(#\S+)?)?)?)@";
$text = "This is my text, it make include a link like http://google.com or http://www.bbc.co.uk";
$replace = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
$text = preg_replace($url_pattern, $replace, $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

You could set this into a little function and apply it as a filter to content before/as you output it onto your page(s) etc.

Comment: Great. Harry, how to now remove filter in one function only. I added add_filter( 'the_content', 'url_auto' );, Now, I just need to remove filter inside shortcodes, or inside one function, how is easier. Answer accepted anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand - Are you saying you only want to apply this url filter to a particular shortcode, or just all shortcodes in general (and not on the_content) - let me know and I'll try to help further!

Comment: I applied it to the_content. I want to remove it inside shortcodes.

Comment: At first I thought this will work, but now I see it always outputs same instead of link:"This is my text, it make include a link like http://google.com or http://www.bbc.co.uk".

Comment: Yes of course it always outputs the same as $text is defined with that example above, you need to change this in your function. Simply set it up as a function with the $text variable as the item passed into the function i.e.
    `function convert_urls($text) {
         //rest of code goes here
    }`

and remember to remove the $text = "this is my text, ...." etc from the function, this way you can pass text/content to the function and filter it with either a string variable or something like get_the_content() in wordpress

Comment: See this = http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/adding-a-filter-to-a-shortcode - For applying a filter to a shortcode(s)

Comment: Ok. I got it. Just now with $url_pattern works untill dash, when dash appears in url, it will stop there and link is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available to do this in WordPress if you don't want to do it programmatically. Here are a couple:

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-hyperlink-urls/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/sem-autolink-uri/

Comment: Completely forgot about this = http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/make_clickable
WordPress's built in URL to Link convert - you can set it as a filter to 'the_content' etc in your functions.php file

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks, I want to do this without plugin.

Comment: Check @HarryFinn comment above for the WordPress codex.